# "collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status" в Qt 4.8.5 при вызове коллбека

Tags: c++

есть функции и по указателю в пространствах имен "metrics.h":

```
namespace Metrics {
    namespace Points {
        double (*D)(mpoint* a, mpoint *b);
        extern double  Euclidean(mpoint* a, mpoint *b);
        double Mahalanobis(mpoint* a, mpoint *b);
    }
    namespace Clusters {
        double  (*D)(Cluster* a, Cluster *b);
        double  Euclidean(  Cluster* a, Cluster *b);
        double  Mahalanobis(Cluster* a, Cluster *b);
    }
}
```

реализация одний из них "metrics.cpp":

```
#include "metrics.h"
namespace Metrics {
namespace Points {
extern double Euclidean(mpoint *a, mpoint *b) {
    return (sqrt( pow((double)(a->x - b->x), 2) +  pow((double)(a->y - b->y), 2) ) );

}
...
}
...
}
```

Присваивание указателя ("metric_select.cpp"):

```
#include "metrics.h"
extern double Metrics::Points::Euclidean(mpoint*, mpoint*);
....
Metrics::Points::D = &(Metrics::Points::Euclidean);
```

Выдает вышеуказанную ошибку, если убрать extern'ы то выдает ее и ошибку 
undefined reference to Metrics::Points::Euclidean в поледней строчке
Что не так? И как исправить?
P.S.:Ответы со словом С++11 не принимается.

UPD:
Написал структуру:

```
typedef struct __D{
    double (*d)(mpoint*, mpoint* );
    double operator () (mpoint*a, mpoint*b) {
        return d(a, b);
    }
    __D& operator = (double(*f)(mpoint*, mpoint*)) {
        d = f;
        return *this;
    }
} Distance;
```

и заменил:

```
double (*D)(mpoint* a, mpoint *b);
```

на
    Distanse D;

в обоих namespace'ах, ошибка та же

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте typedef.

```
typedef double (*Dfunc)(mpoint*, mpoint *) ;
extern Dfunc D;
```

Уберите extern отсюда:

```
extern double Euclidean(mpoint *a, mpoint *b)
```

В metric_select.cpp

```
Metrics::Points::Dfunc Metrics::Points::D = &(Metrics::Points::Euclidean);
```

Comment: мне надо будет потом указателю присваивать значение адреса той или иной функции

Comment: Ну и что вам мешает делать это делать? Зачем городить структуру?
Или вы не понимаете, что такое extern?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы пишете extern рядом с именем переменной, это означает, что переменная будет задана в другом модуле, т.н. compilation unit.
Т.е. если вы пишете:

```
 extern Distanсe D;
```

значит где-то в другом модуле у вас должно быть:

```
Metrics::Points::Distanсe Metrics::Points::D = 0; // инициализируем как-нибудь переменную, иначе получим unresolved external
int main()
{
    Metrics::Points::D = &(Metrics::Points::Euclidean); // теперь D содержит указатель на Euclidean
    Metrics::Points::D = &(Metrics::Points::Mahalanobis); // теперь D содержит указатель на Mahalanobis
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Писать extern рядом с именем функции не имеет смысла.

Comment: Я читал про extern, но спасибо. Все сделал как вы указали, все равно такая же ошибка. Я сомневаюсь что вопрос не глупый, но ведь то, что metrics.h подключен еще и в другом файле никак на это не влияет?

Comment: Вы уверены, что файл metrics.cpp компилируется вместе с проектом?
Выполните на всякий случай qmake.
Сигнатура функции в metrics.cpp и metrics.h совпадает?

Comment: Пересобрал все с очисткой, заработало, спасибо вам!